# Send SIGTERM signal to a process running inside ssh

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to send a SIGTERM (or other) signal to a process inside ssh, for example:

```
ssh hostname 'sleep 10; echo done'
```

What can I do to interrupt the sleep command? If I press ctrl-c, the ssh command gets interrupted.

Comment: Are you looking for something as described in the following question? [How to inject commands at the start of an interactive SSH session?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7660900/320437) Unfortunately the only answer is not probably suitable for you.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to propagate `ctrl+c` through to the remote process by implementing an "EOF to SIGHUP" converter via a named pipe on the remote host (see: [ssh command unexpectedly continues on other system after ssh terminates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74883)).

```
ssh localhost '
TUBE=/tmp/myfifo.fifo
rm -f "$TUBE"
mkfifo "$TUBE"
<"$TUBE" sleep 100 &  appPID=$!
dd of="$TUBE" bs=1 2>/dev/null
kill $appPID
#kill -TERM -- -$$  # kill entire process group
rm -f "$TUBE"
'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you knew the pid of the remote process then you could do: `ssh hostname 'kill -TERM $pid'`

Comment: Pity, I hope this is not the only solution :) Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

-t might do what you want (see https://superuser.com/a/20708/36198). Unfortunately, if you want to read stdin as well, you'll need to do that in two steps, only having Ctrl+C for the second, e.g.

```
tmp=$(bzcat foo.bz2 | ssh $user@$host '
    t=$(mktemp -t foo.XXXXXXXXXXX);
    cat >"$t";
    echo "$t";
')
ssh -t $user@$host "./cmd \"$tmp\""
ssh $user@$host "rm -f \"$tmp\""
```