# ssh: propagate signal to remote process

Tags: ssh, signal

This is the general version of: [Send SIGTERM signal to a process running inside ssh](https://superuser.com/questions/382164/send-sigterm-signal-to-a-process-running-inside-ssh)

It is possible to send Ctrl-C to the remote process if the process gets a pty (-tt):

```
# Runs for 5 seconds
(sleep 5; echo '^C'; sleep 5) | time ssh -tt localhost burnP6
```

I had hoped the same would work for Ctrl-Z, but, alas, no:

```
# Continues to run - does not suspend
(sleep 5; echo '^Z'; sleep 5) | time ssh -tt localhost burnP6
```

If I get an interactive session, Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Z work fine.

Is there a way I can send other signals (I am especially interested in Ctrl-Z)?

I cannot use the suggested "ssh hostname 'kill -TERM $pid'" as I do not know the pids on the remote system.

Comment: What do you mean by "(sleep 5; echo '^C'; sleep 5)"?

Comment: Wait 5 seconds. Send Ctrl-C (ASCII character 3, type Ctrl-V Ctrl-C in Bash). Wait 5 seconds.

Comment: But echoing '^C' does not generate a SIGINT signal. You mean it is pseudocode for doing that by hand?

Comment: It does generate INT on the remote if you use ssh -tt. So no: It is not pseudocode. The above example with ^C actually works.

Comment: Note that Ctrl-Z sends a SIGTSTP, not a SIGTERM. Even if you get Ctrl-Z working you're limited to [Ctrl-C, Ctrl-\, and Ctrl-Z](https://superuser.com/a/343054/16275), not arbitrary signals.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a tty?

You could just use `ssh server killall burnP6` is there is just one process with such name.

Or you could somehow write the IP of your process in a file and then use something like `ssh server kill $(cat /tmp/burnP6.pid)".

Or a simpler and more robust implementation would be to use the package **daemon**, meant to daemonize otherwise non-daemon-featured programs.  It lets you automatically write your daemon's PID to a file and kill it easily.  It can even relaunch your process in case it dies.

To start it:

```
ssh server daemon -n burnP6 -- /usr/bin/burnP6
```

To stop it:

```
ssh server daemon --stop -n burnP6
```

Comment: I do not need a pty, but `burnP6` is just an example. The command could be: `echo fyrrc 10 | rot13 | bash`. In other words you will have no idea of what the command run will be, and other processes may run commands of the same name (and these must be unaffected) so your solution cannot depend on knowing which command will be run. It is also unacceptable to have to type a command: Your solution must be activated by Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Z.